# Цикл неправильно работает

Tags: python

Почему этот цикл бесконечен ? Я не могу найти ошибку .

```
while a != "1" or a != "0":
        a = input("Введите 1 или 0 : ")
input()
```

Участок нужен для программы .

Comment: Потому что `a != "1" or a != "0"` всегда `True`

Comment: А почему string а не integer?

Comment: @Slava потому что из ``input()`` выходит строка.

Comment: @Эникейщик аа вспомнил, забыл. Потом следующей строкой можно изменить тип на integer и проверять цикл, или сразу в этой строке в скобки

Comment: "Работает не так, как я ожидаю" еще не означает "неправильно работает." Цикл работает правильно - как написано, так и работает.

Comment: Всё , спасибо . Я понял свою ошибку .

Answer (score 2):

Или не `or`, а `and`.

В нормальных(КНФ,ДНФ) формах:

```
a != "1" and a != "0"
not (a == "1" or a == "0")
```

Или так, читабельней:

```
a=""
while a not in ["1","0"]:
    a=input("введите 1 или 0")
```

Answer (score 1):

Без инициализации `а` перед циклом:

```
while True:
    a = input("Введите 1 или 0: ")
    if a == "1" or a == "0":
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Верный ответ уже дан, но всё же :D

```
In [1]: from functools import partial

In [2]: inp = partial(input, "Enter: ")

In [3]: class UserInput:
   ...:     def __init__(self, *args):
   ...:         self.args = args
   ...:     def __eq__(self, other):
   ...:         if other in self.args:
   ...:             self.answer = other
   ...:             return True
   ...:

In [4]: user = UserInput(1, 2, 3, '0', '1', 'hello')

In [5]: for i in iter(inp, user):
   ...:     pass
   ...:
Enter: dasd
Enter: sadsadsad
Enter: hello

In [6]: user.answer
Out[6]: 'hello'

In [7]: for i in iter(inp, user):
   ...:     pass
   ...:
Enter: fsf
Enter: fdsfdsfds
Enter: 1

In [8]: user.answer
Out[8]: '1'
```

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте этот код:

```
a=str()
while True:
    if(a=="1"):
        break
    elif(a=="0"):
        break
    else:
        a = str(input("Введите 1 или 0: "))
input()
```

Comment: Слишком много текста для такого простого условия. Да еще в неправильном порядке :) Зачем делать две ветки для одного результата.